# React hooks FlatList pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to let the FlatList get 20 posts from Firestore and render 20. when the end is reached I would like to call the `getPosts` method to get the next 20 posts which means I will have to have a way to save the last known `cursor`. This is what I was trying to do when converting class component to hooks.

Please can someone help me , no one answered my last question about this

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  //How to get 20 posts from firebase and then render 20 more when the end is reached 
  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [isRefreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      var all = [];
      const unsubscribe = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp",'desc')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            all.push(doc.data());
          });
          setLoading(false);
        });
      setAllPosts(all);
      if(currentUser === null){
        unsubscribe()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    getPosts()
      .then(() => {
        setRefreshing(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setRefreshing(false); // false isRefreshing flag for disable pull to refresh
        Alert.alert("An error occured", "Please try again later");
      });
  }, []);

  return (
      <FlatList
        data={allRecipes}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={isRefreshing}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
          />
        }
        initialNumToRender={20}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.postId}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: What are you having problems with specifically?

Comment: Please describe more detail.

Comment: I am trying to set the data state using `setData()` and `setPosts` I saw this code on stack but because I am not good with class components I am trying to convert it to functional components

Comment: what's inside your `render()` method?

Comment: @JoimeeCajandab Returning the react component : `LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut()` How would I convert that to Functional components

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @JoimeeCajandab I updated the code to what I was trying to convert from class to functional component which is get 20 posts from firestore and get 20+ when the end is reached

Answer (score 0):

```
const Posts = () =>{
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const addPosts = posts => {
    setData({...data,...posts})
    // `setData` is async , use posts directly
    setPosts(Object.values(posts).sort((a, b) => a.timestamp < b.timestamp))
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a scroll event listener here

something like:

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= (document.body.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight)) {
     // fetch more posts here
    }
   });
  });

  // ...rest of the codes
}
```

Comment: Wow okay so where would I add that, to the `getPosts` function or ?

Comment: I am getting undefined is not a function `window.addEventListener`

Comment: You might also need to add a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) to prevent the listener from firing simultaneously

Comment: Yeah because my answer is wrong sorry, I was missing the event type

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I have no idea how to add a debounce